# i want to create EEVENT_SCHEDULER on table between user selected daytime and end daytime it creates once when the user select the start day and time

Tags: mysql, events

```
  CREATE EVENT test_event_1
    ON SCHEDULE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ENDS test.end_date
    DO
       INSERT INTO test(title,created_date,end_date)
       VALUES('Test MySQL recurring Event',2021-03-01 08:07:16.141265,2021-03-01 08:08:16.141265);
```

this is my form when the user select the starting day and time also select the end daytime of the event.Event start and end according to user-selected daytime

[image]

this is my table of database when user enter the craeted_date the event start and end end_data of user selected

[image]

Comment: ENDS test.end_date - no can do.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: so how I can create the event-scheduler of user-selected start and end daytime i will share my table please if you have solution please let my know

Comment: an event run at a defined time, you can add parameters throua table which you query, but i ca't see how an event should do what you want

Comment: Not enough information what/how do you mean when the user select daytime of starting... AND what is the event frequency and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: mysql does not have forms - up to you to code for event creation in whatever tech you are using..

Comment: i have one form where the user selects the start daytime and end daytime. the event starts on user-selected start daytime and end event of user-selected end daytime i edit my post please see the picture of fomr and my table

Comment: i am using php codeigniter

Comment: If you're creating the event dynamically when the user submits the form, simply copy the end date into the `ENDS` field (after properly validating its format).

Comment: Then write some php code to create the event - do you have a problem with this ..

Comment: thank you much i will try it

Comment: I creating even dynamically when the user submits the form ... the event start and ending day time are  given by the user  both start and end daytime are dynamic in event

Comment: Note that 2021 minus 03 minus 01 = 2017